# Winsorizing and ratios

Tags: data-preprocessing, winsorizing

Say I have a ratio `c = a/b`.
Should I winsorize both `a` and `b` and then `c` or only `c`?
What is a proper approach?

Update with details.
I have financial data for different companies like income (`a`) and want to scale it by total assets (`b`).

As @gunes commented, even if I winsorize `a` and `b` I'd still have outliers in `c`, so should I skip winsorization of `a` and `b`?

Comment: I think it's dependent on your specific use case and data. But, keep in mind that two outliers may create an non-outlier c, while two non-outliers can create a possible outlier c as well (e.g. when b close to 0). The thing is, what do you want to do with these outliers?

Comment: @gunes thanks, yes, this is what I noticed, I'm trying to do some financial analysis and scale my variables by total assets of a firm, so not sure when to winsorize, prior to scaling, after, or both times.